# How do I prevent/delete old packages in gitlab maven repository

Tags: maven, gitlab

I have a java project built with gradle, that publishes to a GitLab maven repository. The [gitlab maven documentation](https://gitlab.dhkp.net/help/user/packages/maven_repository/index#publishing-a-package-with-the-same-name-or-version) claims the following:

```
When you publish a package with the same name or version as an existing package, 
the existing package is overwritten.
```

But this does not happen. The repository is filling up with old versions of the same package. How can I prevent this from happening and/or delete the old package versions in the repository?